# Does Scrapy Retry twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.AttributeError?

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I get this error sometimes

```
2017-10-05 02:40:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <POST https://example.com/index.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_producer'>]
```

There is also sometimes where it looks like it is corrected:

```
2017-10-05 02:45:23 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <POST https://example.com/index.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
```

So it looks like retrying is working, but is it working for the `twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.AttributeError`?

Comment: If the error is intermittent then I think it something you can ignore